# Convert UK local date/time to UTC date/time in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, utc, dst

I am using a web service which returns a UK date/time in the format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`. By UK date/time, I mean a value local to the UK which takes UK daylight savings into account (i.e. UTC in winter, UTC+1 in summer).

**How can I get the equivalent UTC date?**

I want this to work no matter what the local time zone of the executing machine is - it should simply take a UK local date/time in the format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` and return a UTC date/time.

**** EDIT ****

While the answer to the duplicate question pointed me in the right direction, it did not give an actual solution to my particular question. So here goes:

```
return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(
  DateTime.Parse(sDate, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
  TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time")
);
```

Comment: I would suggest using [nodatime](http://nodatime.org/) for the conversion between time zones.

Comment: @Wimmel: As would I :) But if not, the duplicate question should help the OP.

Comment: What value should it return when passed the value `25/10/2015 01:30`? Datetime formatting is always fraught with peril.

Comment: Thanks guys, that pointed me in right direction. I added solution to question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I tried that using my solution - it causes a System.ArgumentException.